# run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I keep getting this error in my code. I have searched and searched but nothing has remedied the situation. All I am trying to do is have 3 inputs that are typed into a spreadsheet that allow a user to quickly reference them through filters function on the spreadsheet. Please someone help

```
Sub Newnew()

Workbooks("CCP Quick Reference Guide.xls").Activate
Workbooks("CCP Quick Reference Guide.xls").Worksheets("Data").Select

'Dim xx As String
'Dim yy As String
'Dim zz As String



    If Cells(3, 2).Value = "" Then
        'Nothing
    Else
        xx = Cells(3, 2).Value
        Range("A6").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=xx
    End If


    If Cells(3, 3).Value = "" Then
        'Nothing
    Else
        yy = Cells(3, 3).Value
        Range("A6").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=yy
    End If


    If Cells(3, 4).Value = "" Then
        'Nothing
    Else
        zz = Cells(3, 4).Value
        Range("A6").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$I$1000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criterial:=zz
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: What highlights the error?

Answer (score 0):

In your last filter section, the named parameter `Criteria1` is misspelled as `Criterial`--notice the last character should be a **number 1** and not the **letter l**.